# Use AWS SNS to send different messages to 10000 users?

Tags: amazon-sns

I have 10000 users, and i want to push notification SNS to each user, with different message.
So, i cannot use Topic in this case.
The problem is it delay too much. (About 1h30 hour for this to complete)
Any solution?
Thank you so much!

Comment: In publish SDK page - please check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Sns.SnsClient.html#_publish     'Message' => 'string',
    'Subject' => 'string',. Is it not ok for you?

Comment: @Rinat You dont understand my question.

Comment: What do you mean with *difference* in your case. Please ask clear question

Comment: Example: I have 10.000 users. I want to send message with different content:
"Hello user 1" to User 1.
"Hello user 2" to User 2.....
..
"Hello user 10.000" to User 10.000.

Comment: You can send an topic message to specific endPoint. endPoint mean one user. So no problem

Comment: @Rinat: plz give me a guide. I can specify different message content to each platform(ios, android) in a topic (using Json structure).. but dont know how to specify to specific endpoint :(

Comment: I pushed it as answer because this description is quite big for comment message

Answer (score 1):

Endpoint is something like internal AWS Identificator for combination: **platform**+**device token or smth else**. When we want to send an message we use it as address point instead of real.

About adding Endpoint to SNS. Generally it looks like so:

1. You should register your platform in AWS SNS and receive e.g. for IOS - iOS app's Application ARN. It can be done via e.g. AWS Web Console
2. After you should create for each target user its endpoint with method like this:

   ```
   $endPoint = $snsClient->createPlatformEndpoint([
       'PlatformApplicationArn' => $SNS_APP_ARN,
       'Token' => 'phone token'
   ]);
   ```

*phone token* for push notification is device-token. Endpoint generally is array/object which contains **EndpointArn**. Use it address when send message.

3. After that you can send an message to specific endpoint.

   ```
   $snsClient->publish(
       array(
         'Message' => $pushMessage,
         'TargetArn' => $endpointArn
   ));
   ```

Comment: As I remember EndPoint can be created/removed via AWS Console as well(for easy debug/testing purpose)